# How to get a value of the column for the specific(this) row?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a loop in jquery that iterate through each row in a table:

```
var grid = $("#TicketReportPropertyGrid").data("kendoGrid");

grid.tbody.find("tr[role='row']").each(function () {
   var model = grid.dataItem(this);
   if (model.deleted)
       $(this).addClass('disabledGridRow');

   if (model.isNew()) {
       $(this). //here I need to have a logic to disable button for this row
   }
});
```

How can I disable `Delete` button in the 4th column for that specific row if I have the following html:

[image]

Comment: `$('.k-button', this)` or `$(this).find('.k-button')` should do...

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: What's the actual problem? My comment was about how to target it. Your source does not have a `href` attribute. Does it have an event handler? A link cannot be disabled.